# Cannot install expo-cli

Tags: macos, react-native, operating-system, expo

my expo cli has stopped working and now I am unable to run:

```
npm start
```

This prompts me to install expo-cli globally and when I do I get this Error Message:

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  x64
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   darwin
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/steven/.npm/_logs/2020-09-14T13_42_30_485Z-debug.log
```

I really need expo-cli to work for work purposes. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Try running the npm doctor command to check if there's any missing dependency:

```
npm doctor
```

or you could install expo using the **Yarn command**:

```
yarn global add expo-cli
```

Comment: I solved it I had to delete all my global dependencies from node_modules folder.